# React Router Dom v6 shows active for index as well as other subroutes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
<Route path='/dashboard' element={<Navbar />}>
     <Route index element={<Home />} />
     <Route path='profile' element={<Profile />} />
     <Route path='wallets' element={<Wallet />} />
     <Route path='users' element={<Users />} />
</Route>
```

Here's my code and what basically happens is in my Navbar I got the active page link marked blue
So when I'm on `/dashboard` it shows Home in blue
But when I'm on `/dashboard/profile` it shows both home and profile in blue

```
<li>
    <NavLink to=''>
      {({ isActive }) =>
         isActive ? (
               <text style={{color: blue}}>Home</text>
         ) : (                      
               <text>Home</text>
         )
      }
    </NavLink>
</li>
<li>
    <NavLink to='profile'>
    {({ isActive }) =>
         isActive ? (
               <text style={{color: blue}}>Profile</text>
         ) : (                      
               <text>Profile</text>
         )
    }
    </NavLink>
</li>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can specify the `end` prop on the "root"-level link to the `"/dashboard"` path.

[NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/nav-link)

> If the `end` prop is used, it will ensure this component isn't matched
> as "active" when its descendant paths are matched.

```
<NavLink to='' end>
  {({ isActive }) =>
     isActive ? (
           <text style={{color: blue}}>Home</text>
     ) : (                      
           <text>Home</text>
     )
  }
</NavLink>
```

[image: Edit react-router-dom-v6-shows-active-for-index-as-well-as-other-subroutes]

Answer (score 0):

```
 <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
 <NavLink to="/profile">Profile</NavLink>
 <NavLink to="/wallets">Wallet</NavLink>
```

Here React Router considers the /path the same as the /about. By including the end prop, the active class will be applied only when the URL matches its attributes.

```
NavLink to="/profile" style={({isActive}) => isActive ? {background: "hotpink"} : undefined} >Profile</NavLink>
```