# React Router Dome 6 - Active class for NavLink getting applied for all the links

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to make a style for active links, which is created using NavLink from React-Router-Dom version 6.4. So, the problem is the active class is getting applied for all the links when the page loads or it is not being removed once I click another link or vice versa.

Below is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

function NavBar() {

    const NAVSTYLE = ({isActive}) => {
        return {
            fontWeight: (isActive) ? 'bold': 'normal',
            textDecoration: (isActive) ? 'none': 'underline',
        }
    }


    return (
        <nav className='app2Nav'>
            <NavLink to='/' style={NAVSTYLE}>Home</NavLink>
            <NavLink to='/about' style={NAVSTYLE}>About</NavLink>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default NavBar;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bI50F.png)

Any help or tip is much appreciated !!

Comment: Can you try adding `exact` prop to both the `NavLink`? For example: `<NavLink to='/' exact style={NAVSTYLE}>Home</NavLink>`

Comment: Thanks! I have added the exact prop to both, but the issue still persists.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)?

Comment: Sure! Also, I have tried adding further routes. It seems like the active class is not getting removed only for the home route. For the rest of the routes, it is working correctly

Comment: @vighnesh153 please find the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2ezibg?file=src/App.js

Comment: Well, adding a prop 'end' has fixed the issue. Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70644361/react-router-dom-v6-shows-active-for-index-as-well-as-other-subroutes